# RequestFactory Entity's parameter: List<OfOtherEntity> is null on client. On server is ok

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

I am learning RequestFactory. I have simple example working. Now I would like to implement for RF those Entities from below:

---

**Server package**

```
@Entity
public class Pizza implements Identifiable, Versionable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Version
    private Long version;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;
    /* Getters and Setters */
}

@Entity
public class Ingredient implements Identifiable, Versionable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Version
    private Long version;
    private String name;
    private boolean vegan;
    /* Getters and Setters */
}
```

Here is `DAO` class for `Pizza Entity`:

```
@Override
public List<Pizza> get() {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = JPA.em().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Pizza> q = cb.createQuery(Pizza.class);
    Root<Pizza> c = q.from(Pizza.class);
    q.select(c);

    TypedQuery<Pizza> query = JPA.em().createQuery(q);
    List<Pizza> results = query.getResultList();

    for(Pizza p: results) {
        for(Ingredient i: p.getIngredients()) {
            logger.info(i.getName());
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

---

**Shared package**

I wrote Proxies for those classes:

```
@ProxyFor(value = Pizza.class, locator = PizzaLocator.class)
public interface PizzaProxy extends EntityProxy {
  public Long getId();
  public String getName();
  public void setName( String name );
  public Long getVersion();
  public List<IngredientProxy> getIngredients();
  public void setIngredients( List<IngredientProxy> ingredients )
}

@ProxyFor(value = Ingredient.class)
public interface IngredientProxy extends EntityProxy {
    public void setId(Long id);
    public Long getId();
    public Long getVersion();
    public void setVersion(Long version);
    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);
    public boolean isVegan();
    public void setVegan(boolean vegan);
}
```

RF related interfaces:

```
public interface RequestFactoryServices extends RequestFactory {
      PizzaRequest pizzaRequest();
}

@Service(value = PizzaDao.class, locator = DaoLocator.class)
public interface PizzaRequest extends RequestContext {
    Request<PizzaProxy> findById( Long id );
    Request<Void> save( PizzaProxy pizza );
    Request<List<PizzaProxy>> get();
}
```

---

**Client package**

And here is the way I get data from server:

```
List<PizzaProxy> pizzas = new LinkedList<PizzaProxy>();
PizzaRequest context = createFactory().pizzaRequest();
context.get().to(new Receiver<List<PizzaProxy>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<PizzaProxy> response) {
            for(PizzaProxy p: response) {
                RootPanel.get().add(new Label(
                    p.getId() + " " + 
                    p.getName() + ", " + 
                    p.getVersion() + ", " + 
                    p.getIngredients()
                 ));
            }
        }
    }).fire();
```

---

As You can see in `DAO` class in `get()` method I am printing to logger info about ingredients. On the server side it all works.

The problem is that when I call `p.getIngredients()` I am getting `null`, instead of list of `IngredientsProxies`.

Is it happening cause I don't have Dao and Locator classes for `Ingredients` Entity?

Please help.

Answer:
Entity Relationships

Changes to related entities can be persisted in a single request. For example, this code from the DynatableRF sample app in GWT trunk creates a new Person and Address at the same time:

PersonRequest context = requestFactory.personRequest();
AddressProxy address = context.create(AddressProxy.class);
PersonProxy person = context.create(PersonProxy.class);
person.setAddress(address);
context.persist().using(person).fire(...);
RequestFactory automatically sends the whole object graph in a single request. In this case, the implementation of Person.persist() on the server is responsible for persisting the related Address also, which may or may not happen automatically, depending on the ORM framework and how the relationship is defined. Note that RequestFactory does not currently support embedded objects (@Embedded in various ORM frameworks) because it expects every entity to exist independently with its own ID.

When querying the server, RequestFactory does not automatically populate relations in the object graph. To do this, use the with() method on a request and specify the related property name as a String:

Request findReq = requestFactory.personRequest().find(personId).with("address");
It is also necessary to use the with() method to retrieve any properties with types extending ValueProxy. The with() method takes multiple String arguments, so you can specify multiple property names at once. To specify nested properties, use dot notation. Putting it all together, you might have

Request findReq = find(personId).with("phone","address.city","address.zip")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default gwt does not attach collection entities when fetching the object. You need to use the .with("ingredients") on your rf request. Make sure you have a getIngredients method in your pizza class. The rf request context will use this to fetch the ingredients. You may also need to make sure you have a transaction open if you are fetching this from something like hibernate. This will make sure the rf context can use an attached entity when retrieving the ingredients for your pizza.

Note that you don't want to use the with("getIngredients") the rf context will call the get method correctly.

```
context.get().with("ingredients").fire(new Receiver<>)
```

Comment: Can "ingredients" be past somehow type save? I would like to avoid strings as much I can :-)

Comment: I had the same feeling and actually proposed an enhancement to add the @Eager annotation support to the Proxy class in order to identify collections that should be fetched eagerly. I may actually do this myself at some point but have switched to using GWT-RESTY so that my api's are more portable. I have created constants in the proxy as helpers so that I may use something like with(PizzaProxy.Ingredients) instead of having to use the string and change it in multiple places. Keep in mind that this is a significant performance increase to not send collections by default.

Comment: It could be done also with reflection or code generation. Have to wait for Google to implement it.

Comment: Can't be done with reflection effectively due to the lack of reflection in compiled code. Most likely it would have to be implemented in the request factory deferred binding handler.

Comment: A cursory glance says that you could modify this the Resolver class to account for the annotation. I can't remember if it has access to the interface or not but this may work. You would have to replace the class on the server side to get it to work. Check the section dealing with property refs. https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/c9c32256f6ffb8ca69f50693a06b91bc25331fef/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/Resolver.java

Comment: The other spot to add them using reflection into the gwt code would be in the RequestFactoryGenerator. You could have a stable list of properties using an annotation and then change the method to with(String ... paths) to append to the list of properties that were collected from the annotations. https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/c9c32256f6ffb8ca69f50693a06b91bc25331fef/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/gwt/rebind/RequestFactoryGenerator.java

Answer (score 2):

By default, RequestFactory doesn't recursively cause the fetch to happen, to save both DB calls and space on the wire.

If you need the `ingredients` property, you must request it. Instead of

```
context.get().to(...
```

add a call to `Request.with(String... propertyRefs)` in there, and specify that you want ingredients:

```
context.get().with("ingredients").to(...
```

---

Not having a locator for the `Ingredients` type may end up mattering, but you'll get specific errors if you try to use those objects in such a way where either a `Locator` or static methods in the class are required. You do not need a specific DAO and `ServiceLocator` class for it unless you end up making a `RequestContext` type for it.

Comment: Can "ingredients" be past somehow type save? I would like to avoid strings as much I can :-)